# structuremap enrichwith not overriden

Tags: overriding, structuremap

I am trying to find a way to override a structuremap registry statement containing EnrichWith like so (here is the Registry class):

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        For(typeof(IMyList<int>)).EnrichWith(x => DecorateMyList(x)).Use(typeof(MyListA<int>));
        For(typeof(IMyList<int>)).Use(typeof(MyListB<int>));

        For<IMyList<string>>().Use<MyListA<string>>();
        For<IMyList<string>>().Use<MyListB<string>>();
    }

    private object DecorateMyList(object o)
    {
        var genericParameters = o.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
        var myListDecoratorType = typeof(MyListDecorator<>).MakeGenericType(genericParameters);

        var decorated = Activator.CreateInstance(myListDecoratorType, new []{o});
        return decorated;
    }
}

public class MyRegistryUser
{
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyList<string>>(); // Good: Returns an instance of MyListB<string> as expected
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyList<int>>(); // Bad: Returns an instance of the decorator containing MyListB<int> - my second rule should have overridden the EnrichWith as well. 
}
```

Am I right to think that there is a glitch in structure map or is there something I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance